# Why is fields_for not iterating over the passed ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, form-helpers, fields-for

I'm trying to setup a section of the form where a user can select zero or more doctors, but is required to provide a token from each to demonstrate that they spoke to the doctor. Anyway, I have the relationship working on the models, and can set & get lists of doctors and patients. But `fields_for` doesn't seem to understand that. There's probably some magic somewhere that I've missed, and if anyone can point it out that'd be great.

in the controller:

```
def edit
  @doctors = User.doctor
  super
end
```

in the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :registerable

  has_secure_token
  enum role: [:doctor, :admin, :customer, :distributor]
  enum salutation: [:mr, :mrs, :ms, :miss, :dr]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, -> { doctor }, {class_name: "User", join_table: :doctors_patients, foreign_key: :patient_id, association_foreign_key: :doctor_id}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :patients, {class_name: "User", join_table: :doctors_patients, foreign_key: :doctor_id, association_foreign_key: :patient_id}
end
```

in the view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put,class:"form-horizontal" }) do |f|
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :doctors, @doctors do |d| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= d.check_box :id,{checked: resource.doctors.include? d.object.id} %></td>
      <td><%= "#{d.object.salutation.titleize}. #{d.object.last_name}" %></td>
      <td><%= "#{d.object.clinic}" %></td>
      <td><%= d.text_field :token %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'More','#',class:"btn btn-primary",data:{toggle:"modal",target:"#doctor#{d.object.id}Modal"} %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm currently getting an error: `undefined method 'id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faa9392c9b8>` because the entire relation is being used in `fields_for` not one instance at a time.

I'm just trying to implement this:

> Or a collection to be used:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
>   ...
>   <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, @active_projects do |project_fields| %>
>     Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
>   <% end %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :doctors` in your model if you want to get the iteration from `fields_for`.

Answer (score 0):

replace line `<%= f.fields_for :doctors, @doctors do |d| %>` with `<%= f.fields_for :doctor do |d| %>`.

Comment: Read the code again - its actually the controller that is totally wrong - the relations is `has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors`

Comment: I need to populate this list with all the existing doctors regardless of the current relationship.

Comment: In that case, you need to modify the edit method to get list of all doctors. Using `Doctor.all`.

Comment: That's what User.doctor does, it's a scope.